# Mocking and Unit Testing ASP.Net 1.0 Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, mocking

I am in need of some help Mocking and testing my class. I have tried various methods and feel this is the closest I have came. //1 and //2 are two separate attempts. 
There is no error on method one but I do not know how to actually test anything with it using the `Assert` call. 
Attempt 2 has the error message

> Can not instantiate proxy of class: RentalsRated.Data.RentalsDBContext.

**Test**

```
[Fact]
public void RepoUA_GetAll()
{
    var users = new List<UserAccount> {
        new UserAccount { Id = "idstring1", Username = "username1"},
        new UserAccount { Id = "idstring2", Username = "username2" },
        new UserAccount { Id = "idstring3", Username = "username3" },
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockContext = new Mock<RentalsDBContext>();
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<UserAccount>>();

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserAccount>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(users.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserAccount>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(users.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserAccount>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(users.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserAccount>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(users.GetEnumerator());

    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<UserAccount>()).Returns(mockSet.Object).Verifiable();

    //1
    Mock<IRentalsRepository<UserAccount>> MockRepo = new Mock<IRentalsRepository<UserAccount>>();
    MockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(users);

    //2
    var testClass = new RentalsRepository<UserAccount>(mockContext.Object);
    var result = testClass.Get("idstring2");

    Assert.Equal("idstring2", result.Id);
}
```

**Repo**

```
public class RentalsRepository<T> : IRentalsRepository<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    private readonly RentalsDBContext _Context;
    private DbSet<T> entities;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    public RentalsRepository(RentalsDBContext _Context)
    {
        this._Context = _Context;
        entities = _Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return entities.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
public class RentalsDBContext : DbContext
{

    public RentalsDBContext(DbContextOptions<RentalsDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PropertyAddress> PropertyAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Town> Towns { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<County> Countys { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RatingImage> RatingImages { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to be a default constructor for the `RentalsDBContext`  as Moq is unable to instantiate the class with its current constructor.

```
public class RentalsDBContext : DbContext {

    public RentalsDBContext() : base() { }

    public RentalsDBContext(DbContextOptions<RentalsDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```